# Using HTTPS with Azure functions running on Azure iot Edge

Tags: azure, https, azure-functions, azure-iot-edge, azure-functions-proxies

**Background**
I have a system running on Azure iot edge. The system is composed of multiple modules that expose REST interfaces. To make everything look tidy from the client's perspective (a browser on another machine in the same network) we use an Azure Function and its reverse proxy capabilities. 
So, basically, the client makes a request to an endpoint of the function, if the route matches one in the "proxies" config, it is routed to the correct module using the docker network provided by the iot edge product.

**Problem**
Now, what I would like to accomplish is that the client would use an https connection to make the request to the function.
So the browser would make a request to https://:8000/Somemodule/Resource and this request would be routed by the af proxy to http://Somemodule:80/Resource . 
So my question is, how do I enable https in a function running locally in a docker container, and can the reverse proxy work as described above?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For HTTPS, you primarily need a SSL certificate and reverse proxy like nginx that can do SSL Termination since I believe Azure Functions doesn't support it as part of the runtime itself (which is what the docker container has).

Nginx is a popular and fairly common choice to use for SSL Termination. You would have to [configure it for SSL with your domain information](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) and setup your Azure Function as its [upstream](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).

That being said, you could actually just use nginx as your proxy directly too, completely removing the need for Azure Functions, unless you are using it for Functions and Proxies. Your current proxy entries would just become an upstream definition for each module and separate [locations](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) (basically path) that would route the requests.